# Selenium Webdriver, click a button that isn't really a button

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So, i've got this button, thats not a button but is actually three separate table cells(don't know why). But I cannot click it, even by clicking the table, or a point specified that is within the table's confines. I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about clicking this "button" or at least running the script behind it so that the form can be submitted all the same.

```
    <div title="Submit" id="saveUserButton" style="float: right;" fire="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" observe="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" stopObserving="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" visible="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" toggle="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" hide="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" show="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" remove="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" update="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" replace="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" insert="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" wrap="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" inspect="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" recursivelyCollect="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" ancestors="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" descendants="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" firstDescendant="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" immediateDescendants="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" previousSiblings="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" nextSiblings="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" siblings="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" match="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" up="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" down="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" previous="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" next="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" select="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" adjacent="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" identify="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" readAttribute="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" writeAttribute="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" getHeight="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" getWidth="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" classNames="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" hasClassName="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" addClassName="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" removeClassName="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" toggleClassName="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" cleanWhitespace="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" empty="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" descendantOf="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" scrollTo="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" getStyle="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" getOpacity="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" setStyle="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" setOpacity="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" getDimensions="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" makePositioned="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" undoPositioned="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" makeClipping="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" undoClipping="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" cumulativeOffset="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" positionedOffset="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" absolutize="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" relativize="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" cumulativeScrollOffset="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" getOffsetParent="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" viewportOffset="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" clonePosition="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" getElementsBySelector="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" childElements="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" _extendedByPrototype="function() { }" getElementsByClassName="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" childOf="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" morph="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" visualEffect="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" highlight="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" fade="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" appear="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" grow="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" shrink="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" fold="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" blindUp="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" blindDown="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" slideUp="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" slideDown="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" pulsate="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" shake="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" puff="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" squish="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" switchOff="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" dropOut="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" getInlineOpacity="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" forceRerendering="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" setContentZoom="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" collectTextNodes="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" collectTextNodesIgnoreClass="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}" getStyles="function() {
  return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
}">
        <table id="saveUserButton_GlassButtonInnerTable" style="height: 24px;" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-image: url(//GlassButton/EnabledLeft.gif); MIN-WIDTH: 6px; width: 6px;"/>
                    <td style="background-image: url(//GlassButton/EnabledCenter.gif); PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; background-repeat: repeat-x; height: 24px; color: white; overflow: auto; padding-top: 0px;">
                    <td style="background-image: url(//GlassButton/EnabledRight.gif); MIN-WIDTH: 6px; width: 6px;"/>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
```

Anyways, this is part of a ui and it only gets enabled when I fill the form out to standard. The Java code that I am using to click the "button" is below:

```
  //Assuming WebDriver driver works correctly
  WebDriver driver;
  WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("saveUserButton"));
  submit.click();
```

My expected result is that the WebDriver clicks the "button" and then moves onto the next part of the test.

My end result is that the driver does not click the "button" and so stays on the ui, unable to continue.

Comment: have you tried clicking on the td or table element using the [Actions](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) class?

Comment: @Faiz, I tried using that, but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `JavascriptExecutor` in order to perform clicking on an elements which are not links or buttons (Selenium itself is just not able to do that).

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"a[id$='saveUserButton']\").click()");
```

Comment: That seems to click the "button", but it still has no effect. Is there a way to have it just run the javascript behind the button?

Comment: Yeah, @lastexile is right, fire is not an HTML attribute so use `onclick` instead of it. Did you even test that web page manually before you automating the tests?

Comment: I normally do all of the testing by hand, and it works just fine. Supposed to be used in IE, and IE works with some quirky stuff like that. Also, the devs here write it in C#, which I have almost no exposure to. Not sure if that would explain anything. The funny thing is, the way they made this button, I've only seen it once in the entire site, everything else seems to work just fine through Selenium.

Comment: Well, the code I gave you should definitely work so problem probably lies somewhere else - do you have any chance to change the `fire` attribute into `onclick`?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the "fire" attribute before, won't you use "onClick" instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly execute the javascript specified on any of the attributes, you can use `getAttribute()` to get the script and then execute using the `JavascriptExecutor` .

For eg: to execute the script contained in the `fire` attribute of the `div` element:

```
WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("saveUserButton"));

//get the script on 'fire'
String script = submit.getAttribute("fire");

//execute
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript(script);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not result in a submission of the form either, though it does seem to find the script and it does attempt to run it.

Comment: It seems to me that a javascript framework such as `prototype` (check with the devs) is being used to create this button. If you note, all the attributes (`fire`, `observe` etc) have the same script. There is something much more involved, which we don't see here. I would suggest asking devs on how this is implemented(like what script runs on submit) , or use a debug proxy such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what happens when you manually click the button.